# Is there any name for the property denoted by $K \prec f$ or $f \prec V$, where $K, V$ are sets and $f$ is a function?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm studying the proof of the Riesz representation theorem for regular measures using Real and Complex Analysis of Walter Rudin. In page 38, he introduces some notation that reads:

**Notation:**
We denote $K \prec f$ to mean that $K$ is a compact set (o a topological space), $f \in C(X)$, $f : X \to [0, 1]$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in K$.

Similarly, we denote $f \prec V$ to mean that $V$ is open, $f \in C(X)$, $f : X \to [0, 1]$ and $\text{supp}(f) \subseteq V$ (support of $f$).

Is there some name for $K \prec f$ and $f \prec V$?

It would be amazing to have some name for $K \prec f$ (like "$f$ is dominated by $V$" or something similar), since it's somewhat cumbersome to talk about this with the instructor without having a name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any standard terminology (it's sort of an auxiliary notation in his proof of the Riesz' representation theorem, IIRC), but maybe: $f$ is maximal on $K$ for $K \prec f$ and $f$ is supported in $V$ for $f \prec V$ could be used?

Comment: Thank you so much! That terminology helps a lot, even though it would be amazing to have standard terminology for it.